# BigQuery: How to get data with three different filters applied to same column?

Tags: sql, filter, google-bigquery, datefilter

I'm trying to get data for the following conditions in bigquery.
1. Given_Day -> `Calendar_Day = PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020')`
2. last_year_same_day -> `Calendar_Day = DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020'), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)`
3. last_week_same_day -> `Calendar_Day = PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020') - 7`

Above query filter works when used individually, but fails when applied together as `Calendar_Day` equates three conditions.

***Tried Query:***

```
select 
      Calendar_day,
      Sales,
      from `table`
      where
        Calendar_Day = DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020'), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)   #last_year_same_day
        and Calendar_Day = PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020') - 7   #last_week_same_day
        and Calendar_Day = PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020')   #today
```

Need Solution. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  where
    (Calendar_Day = DATE_ADD(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020'), INTERVAL -1 YEAR))   #last_year_same_day
    OR (Calendar_Day = PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020') - 7)   #last_week_same_day
    OR (Calendar_Day = PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y','14/10/2020'))   #today
```

Comment: consider also voting up the answer if it helped. it is equally important on SO

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest:

```
where Calendar_Day in (date('2020-10-14'),
                       date_add(date('2020-10-14'), interval -1 week,
                       date_add(date('2020-10-14'), interval -1 year
                      )
```

I see no reason to parse a date from a non-standard format, if you are passing that value into a query.